# SPFX react solution intrinsic error

Tags: spfx, pnp, reactjs

child component

```
export default class Example extends React.Component<ICState,{sData,cData}> {
constructor(props,state:ICState) {
        super(props);
        sp.setup({
            context: this.props.cData
        });

       
        this.state = {
            arr:[]
          };
        
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
<Example sData="someData" cData={this.props.context}/>
```

If i use State for the child component along with sData and cData i am unable to use child state ICState.
Could anyone please let me know where i am going wrong?

Error Message in Parent component

**Type '{ sData: any; cData: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
Property 'sData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`React.Component` typings](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#class-components) take *props* type as first parameter, so you just need to swap them :

`export default class Example extends React.Component<{sData,cData}, ICState>`